# How to add a builtin function in a GCC plugin?

Tags: c, gcc, built-in, gcc-plugins

It is possible for a GCC plugin to add a new builtin function? If so, how to do it properly?

GCC version is 5.3 (or newer). The code is compiled and processed by the plugin written in C.

It is mentioned in the [rationale for GCC plugins at gcc-melt.org](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/) that this is doable but I cannot see how.

As far as I can see in the sources of GCC, the builtins are created using `add_builtin_function()` from [gcc/langhooks.c](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-5-branch/gcc/langhooks.c#L605):

```
tree
add_builtin_function (const char *name,
      tree type,
      int function_code,
      enum built_in_class cl,
      const char *library_name,
      tree attrs)
```

It is more or less clear which values the arguments of this function should have, except for `function_code`, a unique numeric ID of the function.

Looks like (see `add_builtin_function_common()`), a value from `enum built_in_function` is expected there but a GCC plugin cannot change that enum.

One cannot pass any random value greater than `END_BUILTINS` as `function_code` either, it seems. `builtin_decl_implicit()` and `builtin_decl_explicit()` would have a failed assertion in that case.

So, what is the proper way to add a builtin in a GCC plugin (without using MELT and such, just GCC plugin API)?

**Update**
I looked again at the implementation of `add_builtin_function_common()` and of `langhooks.builtin_function()` for C as well as at how these are used in GCC. It seems that 0 is acceptable as `function_code` in some cases. You cannot use `builtin_decl_implicit()` then but you can save the DECL returned by `add_builtin_function()` and use it later.

Looks like the only event when I can try to create built-ins that way is PLUGIN_START_UNIT (otherwise GCC may crash due to `external_scope` variable being NULL).

I tried the following at that stage (`fntype` was created before):

```
decl = add_builtin_function (
    "my_helper", fntype,
    0 /* function_code */,
    BUILT_IN_NORMAL /* enum built_in_class cl */,
    NULL /* library_name */,
    NULL_TREE /* attrs */)
```

`my_helper` was defined in a different C source file compiled and linked with the main source file. Then I used decl to insert the calls to that function into other functions (`gimple_build_call`) during my GIMPLE pass.

GCC output no errors and indeed inserted the call to `my_helper` but as a call to an ordinary function. I actually needed a builtin to avoid a call but rather insert the body of the function.

On the other hand, `tsan0` pass, which executes right after my pass, inserts the calls of builtin functions just like one would expect: there is no explicit call as a result, just the body of the function is inserted. Its builtins, however, are defined by GCC itself rather than by the plugins.

So I suppose my builtin still needs something to be a valid builtin, but I do not know what it is. What could that be?

Comment: Does the function really need to be a builtin in the gcc sense? Couldn't it be a regular function?

Comment: For the problem I am actually trying to solve (described [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2016-09/msg00026.html) in more detail), it does not have to be a GCC builtin per se. What I need there is a way to insert the code of a C-function does into the code of another one without actually calling the former. Builtins and inlines are obvious choices but I have no luck with both so far. As for this particular question - yes, I am just curious about the builtins. Some say it is possible to add builtins via a GCC plugin but I cannot see how.

Comment: @Nisarg: I have applied the formatting-related part of your edit, thanks. As for the last sentence - no, I did not mean to ask what you suggested. I have replaced it now to make things clearer.

Comment: Have you tried `__attribute__((always_inline))`?

Comment: Yes, but `__attribute__((always_inline))` does not help here. If I mark my function with it and then try to insert the call to it during my GIMPLE pass, GCC either does not find the function or ignores the attribute - I cannot remember now which of these outcomes I got in that case. When I was experimenting with `always_inline` and other attrs like `__unused__`, I got both kinds of errors. I cannot remember which kind I got when.

Comment: My GIMPLE pass needs to run way after inlining passes for some reason, this complicates things.

Comment: For the record, I ended up implementing a simple translation from a sequence of C-like function calls into GIMPLE sequences as a partial workaround for this problem. The GCC plugin inserts these GIMPLE sequences where needed. It cannot "inline" the calls to helpers which it inserts, but it is sufficient for me at the moment. The details are [in this commit](https://github.com/euspectre/kedr/commit/1c40a086341702eb1feff01a4e609fad3538f2e8), see the changes to `i13n/` subdir. Works for me, but making the helpers built-in could be better, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming what you want to do (from your comment and linked post) is insert C code into a function. In that case, I would have thought you wouldn't need to go so far as to write a compiler plugin. Have a look at [Boost.Preprocessor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html), which can do very advanced manipulations of C code using only the preprocessor.

Comment: I intended to use the new builtins in the kernel code, so it is for C language only. I have some experience with Boost and would rather avoid it here. On the other hand, GCC plugins have been supported by the Linux kernel for a while and could probably be used here.

Comment: Preprocessor is a header-only library that works with C and does not require C++. I don't see any reason it shouldn't work in the kernel.

Comment: Well, one never knows until they try ;-) Anyway, as I said in the comments to the question, I already prepared a workaround and it worked OK in 2016, when it was needed. I just wanted to know, perhaps, someone could point to a correct way to create builtins there.