# How to make gcc add a function to executables?

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-plugins

I'm writing a gcc (version 5.4.0) plugin, which is intend to instrument some codes in functions. It's easy to do that by inserting some rtx or gimple instructions in a certain function:

```
a = foo();
instrument codes here;
b = foo();
```

But since the context in functions could be different, I'd like to instrument a call to my function, like:

```
a = foo();
call to instrument my function;
b = foo();
```

The problem is that I can't find a way to add my function, neither in gcc or with plugin. There's a related question: [how-to-add-a-builtin-function-in-a-gcc-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279024/how-to-add-a-builtin-function-in-a-gcc-plugin), but it doesn't solve my problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide some reference about what you try to do -- a reference in the gcc manual -- ?

Comment: I want to append a function to the output elf file, and instrument some calls to the function, with gcc plugin. The function is defined by myself, it can be defined in C file, or created during compiling. Sorry but I didn't find anything related to my problem in [gcc internal](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/).

Comment: If you manage to find a reference within the gcc or some related soft you have bigger chances for other to understand...

Comment: Maybe you want to modify the linker scripts of ld ?
 https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Using_ld_the_GNU_Linker/simple-example.html

Comment: I want to create, and append functions in an optimization pass. GCC allows insertion of new function during compilation, and there is a certain function: `cgraph_node::add_new_function()`. I may modify the instructions in new functions , so I need the internal represents of new functions during compilation(like `treenodes`). ld can be used to add codes to executables, but it won't solve my problem.  The idea is somehow like this one: [https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2016-09/msg00026.html](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2016-09/msg00026.html).

Comment: I think you need and go on @gcc mailing lists and explain them the problem, it is too gcc-specific.  They will provide you the answer within a few hours.  If you get the answer paste it here .